# Read files by folder in R

Tags: r, import

I was trying to read all files in a folder using R, but I always got an error such like that:

```
>folder<-"/Volumes/cphg/projects/PROVIDE/freeze" #working directory
>filelist<-list.files(folder) #all files in the directory
>data<-vector("list", length(filelist)) #empty list
>names(data)<-filelist
>for (name in filelist) {
+           data[[name]]<-read.table(paste(folder, name, sep="/"), header=T)
+}
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
```

Does any body know what' wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any empty files?

Comment: Just checked, 4 out of 72 files are emptyl

Comment: Get the name of the file in which it stops, and look this file, maybe it is some strange format or it is empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch` and return NULL if reading the file fails.  Then you can `Filter` the results to exclude the NULLs

```
L <- setNames(lapply(filelist, function(x) {
  tryCatch(read.table(file.path(folder, name)), error=function(e) NULL)
}), filelist)
data <- Filter(NROW, L)
```

Comment: Good idea, but maybe it is better to know it has failed with some files.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear... and to close the question properly

The problem is that  there is at least one file empty. Check the file name when it through the error.